# How not to miss interesting answers?

Tags: discussion

By now there are so many new questions on Cross Validated that "active" topics disappear from the front page in around 8 hours. This is fast. This means that if I check the website once per day, I will miss a lot of questions that were active during the past 24 horus. This is particularly true because only new answers and edits count as "activity" (as far as I understand), but comments and upvotes do not.

As many (most of the?) questions are very specific and often of no general interest, I have a feeling that it is very easy to miss something really interesting.

So my question is: how do you monitor interesting questions and answers?

I believe that the idea is that worthy stuff should get upvoted, and one can look in the hot/week/month section. However, I noticed that sometimes high quality questions and answers go by without many upvotes -- I guess when the topic is too narrow; questions of very wide appeal often get a lot more upvotes (e.g. the recent question about Facebook).

Of course one can monitor only specific tags, but then one automatically misses a lot.

I noticed that quite often high quality answers to interesting questions have figures in them. I wrote [a query to get last answers with images posted on imgur](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/164585/last-answers-with-figures-hoster-on-imgur-com), but have yet to see whether it turns out to be useful.

Comment: Interesting question. I guess you could check more than once a day, but that may be impractical. And what one person views as interesting may be boring to another.

Comment: I like your query for images: that is useful.  However, I believe it overlooks the majority of posts with images--I'm sure we have more than the 2160 that were returned.  Replacing the "AND" with "OR" seems to do a better job.

Comment: Regarding your query, be aware that the data site is updated only periodically (once a week at most), so rechecking it frequently will not give you any new information.

Comment: The situation isn't *that* dramatic. Checking Q&A using tags isn't too hard and in a way it unclutters ones view. Additionally, checking `hot` questions ensures one hasn't missed a biggie. Having said that, do you really care for a non-hot question that is not included in your specified interests?

Comment: Some relevant (but not really identical) posts you might find useful: [post1](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/are-there-other-ways-to-find-good-recent-answers-on-crossvalidated) [post2](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/the-most-interesting-users-on-cv)

Comment: In addition to the posts @Glen_b notes, you might find [this](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/how-should-a-new-user-navigate-cross-validated-to-learn-more-about-statistics) helpful.

Comment: One option could be to add "follow my favorite tags" page. In other words a user could choose which tags to follow and those would be automatically added to the page. Questions that the user have not seen in last visits could be highlighted. Then that page could be sorted based on number of views, votes, etc.

Comment: I like the idea of having a "hot topics this week" tab, as suggested in the question, determined by those questions with the most upvotes/activity during the week. Of course, if a question is missed (no votes), then there is still a problem.

Comment: @Drew75: this tab exists.